# How to send email using nodemailer in react js?

Tags: reactjs, nodemailer

Nodemailer code

```
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  service: '',
  auth: {
    user: '',
    pass: ''
  }
});

var mailOptions = {
  from: '',
  to: '',
  subject: '',
  text: ``
};

transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info){
  if (error) {
    console.log(error);
  } else {
    console.log('Email sent: ' + info.response);
  }
});
```

I have nodemailer source code above . How can i use above code to send emails in react js ?  please help me out from this

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow Fayaz! What do you mean by "send emails in react js"? Nodemailer is run in node, and React is typically used in the browser.

Comment: Hi Tholle, thanks for the response. actually i wants to send a emergency mail on click(FYI i am working on SOS emergency app). will you please help me how can igenerate a mail using react js / nodemailer...

Comment: React is for frontend (UI), sending emails and stuff like that should be done on backend. Whatever server you are running for backend, in that code you need to handle sending mails.